# Devexpress XtraReport custom XrTable, XrTableRow, XrTableCell

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

I would like to create custom XrTable (e.g. : MyXrTable that contains MyXrTableRows/MyXrTableCells) control with some additional properties.

Is there any way ho to implement this? I think that it should be a workaround because there is no official support from DevExpress for this.

I have found following topics about this problem:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S133680.aspx
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q314421.aspx

Note: There is no problem to create custom control based on XrLabel or XrPanel but XrTable is more complex control.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to get guaranteed assistance with any DevExpress controls is contacting with [DevExpress Support](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) directly.

P.S. Note that FULL SUPPORT IS FREE during the evaluation period (30 days).